# how to get the text between two nodes using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I do not know how to get the values when the nodes have the same text.

here is the xml data.

```
<dict>
    <key>VALUE1</key>
    <dict>
        <key>us</key>
        <string>Zubehör</string>
        <key>fr</key>
        <string>Accessories</string>
    </dict>

    <key>VALUE2</key>
    <dict>
        <key>us</key>
        <string>test2</string>
        <key>fr</key>
        <string>test</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

How do i get the value `VALUE1` by searching for the text `Accessories`? The real list is much larger. The only text given is `Accessories`. And with it I need to find its parent's sibling text --> `VALUE1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one possible way, given such description and that tiny sample XML :

```
//dict[dict/string = 'Accessories']/key
```

We can't be sure enough though, that this will work correctly with the actual XML since the sample XML posted contains *only* the target element.

**update :**

To respond to the updated XML sample, you can try this way :

```
//dict/dict[string = 'Accessories']/preceding-sibling::key[1]
```

The xpath locates `dict` element containing the keyword string, and then return the first preceding sibling `key` element.

Comment: Hi, sorry troubling you more. I have edited the question. Answer posted finds all keys. The edited question now contains 2 keys. If it works for these 2, then it should work for all 400 keys.

Comment: Hey man, i know you probably busy, but i've had no luck with this last part. How do i make this query say filter by two values? Right now your answer correctly finds the key that has the string called `Accessories` but how can it be done to show the key that has the string called `Accessories` with the key `fr`? Basically im trying to filter but not just the string only, but also by its key. I have tried this so far  //dict/dict[string = "Accessories"][key = 'fr']/preceding-sibling::key[1]/text() . But how to make sure string-ACCESSORIES and key-FR are right next to each other? .sry to bug u

Comment: Suggestion: Don't depend on one user here, one maybe busy at a time, and at the same time many others are ready to help. What you are asking now is not in the original question, so you can post a new question for that (it won't/shouldn't be flagged as duplicate of this question), post the XPath you have so far, and notify me that you have posted a new question via comment like the above. This way, I know where to help further if I have time, otherwise many other users will have chance to take my place to help you.

Comment: understood. I'll mess with it some more then post new question if i cant find it out. Thanks.

Comment: @Jai try this way : `//dict/dict[key[.='fr' and following-sibling::string[1][.='Accessories']]]/preceding-sibling::key[1]`